# What is the definition of the stable manifold corresponding to a connected component $C$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \times X \rightarrow X$ be a flow on $X$.
Consider the set  $\mathcal{F}= \lbrace  p \in X , \phi_t(p)= p \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace  $

From Wikipedia, the stable manifolds of $\phi$ are the manifolds of the form
$W_p= \lbrace  q \in X , \phi_n(q) \rightarrow p, n \rightarrow + \infty \rbrace $, where  $p \in \mathcal{F}$.

**Question :** Let $C$ be a connected component of $\mathcal{F}$. In proposition 3.9 of the paper in this link https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01232026?noAccess=true I didn't understand what is meant by  " we denote by $M_C$ the stable manifold corresponding to $C$".  How is $M_C$ defined, is it the union of $W_p$, where $p \in C$ ?

[image]

Comment: That paper costs $40 to read. Can you post the relevant text here?

Comment: @JohnDouma, I've edited My question.